# How to retrieve multilingual domain model?

Tags: domain-driven-design, multilingual, ddd-repositories

I have a lot of entities with 3 language columns: DescriptionNL, DescriptionFR and DescriptionDE (Description, Info, Article, ... all in 3 languages).

My idea was to create a forth property `Description` which return the right value according to the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName`.

But a drawback is that when you have a `GetAll()` method in your repository for a dropdownlist or something else, you return the 3 values to the application layer. So extra network traffic.

Adding a parameter language to the domain services to retrieve data is also "not done" according to DDD experts. The reason is that the language is part of the UI, not the Domain. So what is the best method to retrieve your models with the right description?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in stating that a language has no bearing on a domain model.  If you need to manipulate objects or data you will need to use some canonical form of that data.  This only applies to situation where the value has any kind of meaning in your domain.  Anything that is there only for classification may not interest your model but it may be useful to still use a canonical value.

The added benefit of a canonical value is that you know what the value represent even across systems as you can do a mapping.

A canonical approach that was used on one of my previous projects had data sets with descriptions in various languages, yet the keys were the same for each value.  For instance, `Mr` is key 1, whereas `Mrs` is key 2.  Now in French `M.` would be key 1 and `Mme` would be key 2.  These values are your organisational values.  Now let's assume you have System A and System B.  In System A `Mr` is value 67 and in System B `Mr` is value 22.  Now you can map to these values via your canonical values.

You wouldn't necessarily store these as entities in a repository but they should be in some read model that can be easily queried.  The trip to the database should not be too big of a deal as you could cache the results along with a version number or expiry date.

Comment: Drop the NL, DE, FR, EN, ... columns in the database and use a unique code instead. Create a code table with the different language version for this code. And let the Application layer choose the language version for the corresponding code?

Comment: That is correct.  What we did was request a dataset by name and version.  That url would be cached by the browser so performance was fine.  These are not supposed to be huge files anyway.  The metadata for each dataset was stored locally since you need to know which version you are after.  Metadata would never cache.